# Сортировка и подсчет строк в списке без учёта регистра

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, сортировка, list

**Необходимо написать программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось**. Если таких слов несколько, вывести лексикографически первое (можно использовать оператор < для строк).

Слова, написанные в разных регистрах, считаются одинаковыми.

```
Sample Input:
abc a bCd bC AbC BC BCD bcd ABC
Sample Output:
abc 3
```

Пытался реализовать задачу разными методами, однако в итоге получается не то.

Пример кода:

```
lst = []
maX = {}
with open("someinputfile.txt", 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        lst.extend(line.split())
for i in lst:
    maX.update({i:lst.count(i)})
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as out:
    out.write(str(maX))
```

Необходимо считать `i` в разных регистрах и обновить значения в словаре, по коду который в примере получится словарь `{'AbC': 1, 'BC': 1, 'a': 1, 'BCD': 1, 'bcd': 1, 'abc': 1, 'ABC': 1, 'bC': 1, 'bCd': 1}`

**Подскажите, какими методами можно считывать строки в разных регистрах или возможные реализации данной задачи?**

Comment: Поскольку регистр Вам неважен, можно банально приводить все строки к одному регистру: `lst.extend(line.lower().split())`

Comment: @andy.37: нужно `.casefold()` использовать для Юникодных строк для сравнения без учёта регистра вместо `.lower()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код в вопросе уже подсчитывает частоту слов, разделённых пробелами,  с учётом регистра (не эффективно и не идиоматично, но код должен работать).

Чтобы считать слова без учёта регистра достаточно вызвать [`line.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold).

Чтобы учесть условие: *"Если таких слов несколько, вывести лексикографически первое"*, имея словарь с частотами слов:

```
counter = {'bcd': 3, 'abc': 3, 'bc': 2, 'a': 1}
max_count = max(counter.values())
print(*min(p for p in counter.items() if p[1] == max_count))
# -> abc 3
```

Сортировка здесь не нужна так как все пары просматриваются, чтобы найти самые популярные слова.

---

Вот полный пример кода, который выводит лексикографически-первое слово, из самых популярных слов во вводе без учёта регистра (`top-word.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(word for line in fileinput.input() for word in line.casefold().split())
max_count = max(c.values())
print(*min(p for p in c.items() if p[1] == max_count))
```

[`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) читает строки со стандартного ввода (`stdin`) или из файлов, указанных в командной строке (`argv`). [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) подсчитывает частоту повторения полученных слов.

Пример использования:

```
$ top-word input-file.txt >output-file.txt
```

> **Q:** Функция '*min' что делает?

[`min()` функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) находит минимум:

```
min(['abc', 'bcd']) == 'abc'  # 'abc' < 'bcd'
```

`*` (звёдочка) перед именем -- это специальный оператор, который распаковывает возвращаемую `min()` пару `('abc', 3)` и передает её в `print()` функцию как отдельные параметры:

```
p = ['abc', 3]
print(*p)
```

это тоже самое что:

```
p = ['abc', 3]
print(p[0], p[1])
```

то есть просто:

```
print('abc', 3)
```

[Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5/594652#594652)

> **Q:** И можно итог выразить не печатая, а записывать как 'abc 3' в файл?

Чтобы в файл записать, достаточно `file` параметр указать:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    print('abc', 3, file=file)
```

Comment: не по ответу, @jfs, а как долго вы с питоном знакомы?

Comment: @gil9red: 1- достаточно давно, что иногда когда возникает вопрос, читая ответ на Stack Overflow, не сразу узнаю, что я автор ответа. 2- Общие вопросы лучше в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) или если уведомления там не срабатывают, то по почте ([в профиле](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs)).

Comment: Функция '*min' что делает? И можно итог выразить не печатая, а записывать как 'abc 3' в файл? Все в set записывает.

Comment: На выходу получился почти лаконичный код, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = 'abc a bCd bC AbC BC BCD bcd ABC'.split()
>>> l
['abc', 'a', 'bCd', 'bC', 'AbC', 'BC', 'BCD', 'bcd', 'ABC']
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> c
Counter({'AbC': 1, 'ABC': 1, 'bCd': 1, 'abc': 1, 'bcd': 1, 'a': 1, 'BCD': 1, 'BC': 1, 'bC': 1})
>>> for k, v in c.items():
...     k, v
...
('AbC', 1)
('ABC', 1)
('bCd', 1)
('abc', 1)
('bcd', 1)
('a', 1)
('BCD', 1)
('BC', 1)
('bC', 1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **В итоге получился такой код:**

```
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(word for line in fileinput.input(files=('dataset_3363_3.txt')) for word in line.casefold().split())
max_count = max(c.values())
f1 = open("1.txt", "w+")
print(*min(p for p in c.items() if p[1] == max_count), file = f1)
```

Comment: 1- скобки вокруг `*min()`следует убрать, иначе `SyntaxError` получится. 2- также скобки вокруг строки бесполезны:  `('abc') == 'abc'` 3- с одним именем `fileinput.input` в этом случае не имеет смысла использовать, можно просто `open('dataset_3363_3.txt')` вызвать, чтобы файл получить. 4- используйте `with`-конструкцию  при открытии файлов чтобы закрыть их автоматически.